# How to preserve row structure from sapply when adding multiple values

Tags: r, data.table, sapply

Suppose I have a data.table

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(term = c('dog', 'cat', 'fish', 'dog', 'cat', 'fish', 
                      'dog', 'cat', 'fish', 'dog', 'cat', 'fish',
                      'dog', 'cat', 'fish', 'dog', 'cat', 'fish'), 
             eats = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), 
             weights = c(6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2))
```

I then create a function to perform a correlation between what they eat and what they weigh and return a result for a given pet:

```
foo <- function(pet, dtSrc){
  newDt <- dtSrc[term == pet, c('eats', 'weights')]
  corTotal <- Hmisc::rcorr(as.matrix(newDt), type = 'pearson')  
  corValues <- corTotal$r[1, 2]
  return(corValues)
}
```

I can get the correlation between what they eat and weigh for each pet by running it through the foo function.  Using sapply, I can do something like this:

```
pets <- unique(dt$term)
dtResult <- sapply(pets, foo, dtSrc = dt)
dtResult <- as.data.table(dtResult, keep.rownames = TRUE)
colnames(dtResult) <- c('pet', 'cor')
```

The result is perfect.  I get a single row for each pet

```
    pet       cor
1:  dog -0.8696263
2:  cat -0.8215838
3: fish -0.7364854
```

But if I also want to add p-value data to each row so I can get a result that looks like this:

```
    pet       cor    pv
1:  dog -0.8696263   0.02438794
2:  cat -0.8215838   0.04490880 
3: fish -0.7364854   0.09501072
```

I thought I could add the p-value to the correlation, maybe like this:

```
fooMore <- function(pet, dtSrc){
  newDt <- dtSrc[term == pet, c('eats', 'weights')]
  corTotal <- Hmisc::rcorr(as.matrix(newDt), type = 'pearson')  
  corValues <- corTotal$r[1, 2]
  pValues <- corTotal$P[1, 2]
  result <- c(corValues, pValues)
  return(result)
}

pets <- unique(dt$term)
dtResult <- sapply(pets, fooMore, dtSrc = dt)
dtResult <- as.data.table(dtResult, keep.rownames = TRUE)
colnames(dtResult) <- c('pet', 'cor', 'pv')
```

Unfortunately, the results don't look anything like they did before.  In particular, I don't get the rownames I need:

```
         pet        cor          pv
[1,] -0.86962634 -0.8215838 -0.73648536
[2,]  0.02438794  0.0449088  0.09501072
```

What would be the most R-ish way to modify the code above to generate the result I am looking for?  TIA

Comment: The data.table way to do this is: `dt[, .(eats=sum(eats), weights=mean(weights)), by = term]`.

Comment: You are correct, unfortunately in my 'real' world situation I need to use one of the apply functions.  Long story short - I have measurements from various sensors and run correlations across thousands of different permutations.  I send back correlation values and want to include the corresponding p-values but the extra value causes this problem.  I could run the p-values separately, but want to avoid the extra overhead, hence, this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all I could get was a downvote (dang! that's harsh) I'll post the workaround, although I would welcome a better solution.  As you can see, I simply combine the values and separate them later.  Ugly but at least I don't have to run the same operation twice.

```
fooMore <- function(pet, dtSrc){
  newDt <- dtSrc[term == pet, c('eats', 'weights')]
  corTotal <- Hmisc::rcorr(as.matrix(newDt), type = 'pearson')  
  corValues <- corTotal$r[1, 2]
  pValues <- corTotal$P[1, 2]
  resultBoth <- paste0(corValues, ':', pValues) # combine results
  return(resultBoth)
}

pets <- unique(dt$term)
dtResult <- sapply(pets, fooMore, dtSrc = dt)
dtResult <- as.data.table(dtResult, keep.rownames = TRUE)
dtResult[, c('corValue', 'pValue') := tstrsplit(dtResult, ":", fixed=TRUE)]  # split them back out
dtResult$corValue <- as.numeric(dtResult$corValue)
dtResult$pValue <- as.numeric(dtResult$pValue)
dtResult$dtResult <- NULL
# just to be consistent with earlier
colnames(dtResult) <- c('pet', 'cor', 'pv')

    pet        cor         pv
1:  dog -0.8696263 0.02438794
2:  cat -0.8215838 0.04490880
3: fish -0.7364854 0.09501072
```